# How to compile and run java with package

Tags: java

HI I'm having trouble with my java compille
I made folder named 'Test'. In this folder i make two folders, one is src, another one is bin. Then I made Test. java in that src folder

```
package Test;
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

i saved it and back at Test folder and then i compile like this

```
javac -d bin src/Test.java
```

Thus, i have Test folder in bin folder.

finally in Test folder i write this command

```
java -cp bin/Test Test
```

unfortunately, it says can't find Test class

How can i run this code???

Comment: `java -cp bin Test.Test`

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how that works?

Comment: The package creates a sub directory Test, where the Test.class file resides.

Comment: So Test.Test means in Test folder, it has Test class? am i right?

Comment: Note about Java naming conventions: Package names are typically all lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

When your class is in a package, the name of the class ***includes*** the package. Thus `Test.Test` is the `Test` class in the `Test` package. `-cp bin` tells java that the classpath starts in `bin`.

```
java -cp bin Test.Test
#  classpath main-class
```

Answer (score 2):

"-cp" expects a directory, not a file. Give it the `./bin/` directory, not the file you're trying to execute.

`java -cp bin Test.Test`

Comment: but it says same message that i got

Comment: Elliott Frisch is correct, but my statement regarding `-cp` was also correct. I misunderstood your question when I wrote my code sample, but everything else is correct.